# Extra inter-line space becomes visible then loading package listings inside amsbook

Tags: listings, amsbook

I am typesetting a document using `amsbook`. In the document I would like to print some computer code using the `listings` package. However, it turns out that the options `backgroundcolor` and `frame` cause an extra(?) space to become visible in-between the output code lines. The extra space is a little less than `1pt`. Here is a minimum working example:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}  %%% Works fine %%%
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
frame=l,
backgroundcolor=\color{gray}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a = b
c = d
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Any clue on where to start looking for the bug is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: Based on Barbara's answer below, I added the following:

```
\let\oldlstinputlisting\lstinputlisting%
\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{%
  \normallineskiplimit=0pt%
  \oldlstinputlisting[#1]{#2}%
  \mbox{}%
}
```

after `\usepackage{listings}`. This works for my purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that `amsbook` sets `\lineskiplimit` and `\normallineskiplimit` to `1pt`.

this is necessary when a document contains lots of in-line math; otherwise there is
a high probability of "crashing" lines.  this is what is expected in ams document classes.

`latex.ltx` defines `\normalbaselines` as

```
\def\normalbaselines{\lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit}
```

and in turn, the `listings` package applies `\normalbaselines`.

what is needed is to set `\normallineskiplimit=0pt` for the listing.

my inclination is to set it *only* for the duration of the listing, but i haven't
figured out how to do that neatly.  (it's trivial to do it globally, but whether or not that is a good idea depends on the nature of the document.)

**edit:** neither of the two hooks mentioned by jubobs worked for me, but this did:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{\normallineskiplimit=0pt}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: *my inclination is to set it only for the duration of the listing  but i haven't figured out how to do that neatly.* I haven't tested this, but try to use the `Init` or `PreInit` hooks: `\lst@AddToHook{Init}{<your-modification>}`.

Comment: I followed your advice and it works. I am amazed how much people seem to know and how quick they react!

Comment: I mean Barbara's advice! Sorry.

Comment: @ToreH-W -- glad it worked.  (i've refined the answer to show code that worked for me, after some digging.  it was worth digging, since some ams author might ask the same question sometime, and this can usefully be added to the ams author faq.)

Comment: @ToreH-W -- by the way, if this solves your problem, you might consider accepting it.  (there's a green check mark near the top left that you can click to accept.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Cool. I just had the wrong hooks in mind.

Comment: @ToreH-W Remember to accept (and upvote) barbara's answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: thanks, @jubobs -- your suggestion to use an available existing hook led me to the right place.  i don't use `listings`, and no one here remembers having seen it used in an ams publication (at least, it didn't raise any questions if it was), so it would have taken a lot longer for me to find it on my own.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My pleasure. This is why Stack Exchange (and TeX.SE) in particular is such a great platform. I like to think of it as "crowdsourcing of knowledge" `:)`